# Improper integral calculation - limit at infinity

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Will you please help me prove the following limit is zero ?

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-u^4}}{u^2} \cos(x u) du.  
> $$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Hint:** Check [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)

Comment: Great. Thanks !

Comment: @proplan: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to appeal to Riemann-Lebesgue, you could also try integrating by parts (being careful to justify the differentiability at 0 of $u\mapsto (1-{\rm e}^{-u^4})/u^2$).